# Максимальный поток

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Если ли какой-нибудь алгоритм поиска максимального потока при условии что вершины тоже имеют вес

Comment: Вершины имеют не вес, а пропускную способность, да?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, для этого каждая вершина `v` расщепляется на две:

`v-` - вершина, в которую будут входить все ребра, которые входили в вершину `v`
`v+` - вершина, из которой будут выходить все ребра, которые выходили из вершины `v`

А также в граф добавляется ребро `(v-, v+)` с пропускной способностью, равной пропускной способности исходной вершины `v`. Затем решается обычная задача нахождения максимального потока.

Comment: А если граф неориентированный?
Или есть хотя бы часть неориентированных ребер

Comment: @lokida  Понятие макс. потока - для транспортных сетей, которые являются орграфами. Для неориентированного - ребра расщепляют на пары противоположных дуг.